# LP - Dual variable is zero implies primal constraint unnecessary?

Tags: linear-programming

Say I have a primal program P with n variables and c constraints.
Let's say that I have an optimal solution for the dual program D, in which the y1, the variable related to the first constraint in P, is zero. 
Does that imply that I could run Simplex on P without the first constraint and get the same optimal solution as if ran Simplex with the first constraint?

Comment: Look up *complementary slackness*.